# Unable to link ledger with TezBox

Tags: ledger

Lost my Tezbox 14 months ago .I Linked my Nano S 
with Tezbox. Tezbox received two addresses from my Hard Wallet.
tz1....address  and  a 2yE....Address.I set a password and encrypted Wallet with password.Tezbox was set up with a public address.I then deposited a considerable amount of XTZ over a period
of time.How do I restore my Wallet.Thank you.

Comment: You can use ledger live if you used a ledger to store your xtz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

14 months have passed so you'll want to ensure your ledger nano s firmware AND "tezo wallet" ledger companion app is up-to date and you're using a current version of Tezbox. Helpful [Instructions here.](https://cryptosec.info/store-your-tezos/#ledger)

Comment: @Sue if you like this answer and this resolves your problem then please upvote it and mark the answer as “accepted”